# Awk/Gawk not working after install gawk on M1

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew, apple-silicon

Using brew, I installed gawk on my m1. upon doing so, awk does not work.
Before install gawk:

```
❯ awk -version
awk version 20200816
❯ which awk
/usr/bin/awk
```

Then I install gawk and add the path to the binary to my $PATH

```
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/gawk-5.1.0.arm64_big_sur.bo
Already downloaded: /Users/jtsmith/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/78854a178070158dd17ca1789b20ecabe69f924bad7052337c019a8efeb30178--gawk-5.1.0.arm64_big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring gawk-5.1.0.arm64_big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gawk/5.1.0: 90 files, 5.4MB

❯ which awk
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gawk/5.1.0/bin/awk
```

Now, if I try to use awk/gawk, it always results in a `killed`

```
❯ awk -version
[1]    10790 killed     awk -version
❯ gawk -version
[1]    10796 killed     gawk -version
❯ echo "test test" | awk '{ gsub(/ /,""); print $0}';
[1]    10800 done       echo "test test" |
       10801 killed     awk '{ gsub(/ /,""); print $0}'
```

I assume they are clashing but can't figure out what's going on.

Additional details:

```
❯ /usr/bin/awk -version 
awk version 20200816
❯ /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gawk/5.1.0/bin/gawk -version  
[1]    12436 killed     /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gawk/5.1.0/bin/gawk -version
```

Comment: What does /usr/bin/awk -version show . The two crashes you give are for the same executable

Comment: System Preferences Security & Privacy, Privacy Tab, Select Developer Tools where the right hand window gets a legend `Allow the apps below to run software locally that does not meet the system's security policy.` Check mark Terminal (and any other terminal app, such as iTerm.app) in the right hand window.

Comment: @mmmmmm 
```❯ /usr/bin/awk -version
awk version 20200816```

@user90735 no change

Comment: @mmmmmm ```❯ /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gawk/5.1.0/bin/gawk -version

[1]    12436 killed     /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gawk/5.1.0/bin/gawk -version```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with git. After reinstalling MacOS the issue went away.